# How to use Two QueryStringParameter in SelectCommand

Tags: asp.net

I want to know how to pass two  `QueryStringParameter` from two different pages to `SelectCommand`.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:con %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [admin_video] where c_id=@c_id OR c_name=@c_name" >
    <SelectParameters>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter  Name="c_id" QueryStringField="id1" DbType="Int32"/>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter  Name="c_name" QueryStringField="id2" />

    </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Page:1
`<a href="page1.aspx?id1=<%# Eval("c_name") %>"`
Page:1
`<a href="page2.aspx?id2=<%# Eval("c_id") %>"`
Everything is fine but when i use one only it work but when i use both it not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to modify SQL Command like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [admin_video] where c_id=IsNULL(@c_id,c_id) OR c_name=IsNULL(@c_name, c_name)
```

Comment: i passing two string from two different pages because there is some condition.

Comment: Then you will need to share more about what you mean by two pages. You can use session variable from page one that you can read on page 2

Comment: i write in my question that i am passing `StringPerameter` from two different pages.and you can see `SelectCommand`.The both attribute of database is in same table but i want to match one of string in them because i write `OR` in query.User can access that page from two other pages which have queryString.So tell me what if user want to access this pages from `Page1` with `ID1` to match `C_ID` or from `Page2` with `ID2` to match `C_NAME`..

Comment: Ok then you need to modify sql

Comment: you need to make sure that you pass null when user has not specified anything.

Comment: it have no `null` value because i check the value by `Responce.Write("Here queryString");`

Comment: i check everything but when i use one QueryString at a time then it work but the both one at a time not working

Comment: Ok. You need to basically use like this in your sql where clause. select * From emp_master 
where emp_last_name= 
case emp_first_name 
 when 'test'    then 'test' 
 when 'Mr name' then 'name'
end